# How to download a file using HTTPS connection using VBSCRIPT and by accepting all the certiifcates

Tags: https, vbscript, certificate

I have a script which is able to download files from the https://mysite.com/xxx.zip but when it goes to a secured link, I want to accept the certificate. There is a huge problem here. I am not able to use "ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback" effectively.

Can anyone please help?

I also have the domain for the certificate site: *.mysite.com

code:

```
Const scriptVer  = "1.0"
Const DownloadDest = "https://mysite.com/xxx.zip"
Const LocalFile = "F:\Testing\xxx.zip"
Const webUser = "admin"
Const webPass = "admin"
Const DownloadType = "binary"
dim strURL

function getit()
  dim xmlhttp

  set xmlhttp=createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
  'xmlhttp.SetOption 2, 13056 'If https -> Ignore all SSL errors
  strURL = DownloadDest
  Wscript.Echo "Download-URL: " & strURL

  'For basic auth, use the line below together with user+pass variables above
  xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false, WebUser, WebPass
  'xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false

  xmlhttp.Send
  Wscript.Echo "Download-Status: " & xmlhttp.Status & " " & xmlhttp.statusText

  If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
    Dim objStream
    set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody
    objStream.SaveToFile LocalFile
    objStream.Close
    set objStream = Nothing
  End If


  set xmlhttp=Nothing
End function 

'=======================================================================
' End Function Defs, Start Main
'=======================================================================
' Get cmdline params and initialize variables
If Wscript.Arguments.Named.Exists("h") Then
  Wscript.Echo "Usage: http-download.vbs"
  Wscript.Echo "version " & scriptVer
  WScript.Quit(intOK)
End If

getit()
Wscript.Echo "Download Complete. See " & LocalFile & " for success."
Wscript.Quit(intOK)

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

Private Shared Function ValidateCertificate(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

`ServicePointManager` is a `.NET` class, so it can't be used in `VBScript`. Try this instead:

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.setOption 2, 13056
```

You **must** use `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` here, because `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` requests don't have the `setOption` method.

And perhaps you shouldn't [broadcast](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=99201) your questions. It's not very polite.